# Exponential integration

Tags: integration

I am working for an investment institution and we need to use upper partial moments. To evaluate them, I need to integrate

$$  \int_a^\infty x^2 e^{-ax^2} dx  $$

with $a>0$. I found this formula online :

$$ \int x^2 e^{-ax^2} dx = \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^3}}erf \left(x\sqrt{a} \right) - \frac{x}{2a}e^{-ax^2} $$

I was hoping someone can help me prove it so I can be convinced before I use it. Thanks!

Comment: Try differentiating the right hand side?

Comment: Alternatively, apply integration by parts to $\int e^{-a x^2} dx$

Comment: @KennyLau is right.  If you already know the answer, checking it is easy!  No integration by parts needed any more.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$\int_0^ue^{-t^2}\mathrm dt=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\mbox{erf}(u)$$

Letting $t=x\sqrt a$, $u=w\sqrt a$:

$$\int_0^we^{-ax^2}\mathrm dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt a}\mbox{erf}\left(\frac{w}{\sqrt a}\right)$$

Also:

$\displaystyle\quad\int\mbox{erf}(x)\ \mathrm dx$

$\displaystyle=x\mbox{erf}(x)-\int x\ \mathrm d\left(\mbox{erf}(x)\right)$

$\displaystyle=x\mbox{erf}(x)-\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int xe^{-x^2}\ \mathrm dx$

$\displaystyle=x\mbox{erf}(x)+\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int e^{-x^2}\ \mathrm d(-x^2)$

$\displaystyle=x\mbox{erf}(x)+\frac1{\sqrt\pi}e^{-x^2}+C$

The rest of the proof is left to the reader as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most common asked question. If you google it, you will find many links explain different ways to solve such integrals.
Let us try ourselves, 
\begin{align}
\int{x^2 e^{(-a x^2)}}dx=\int{x (x e^{(-a x^2)})}dx=x\int{x e^{(-a x^2)}dx}-\int{\int{x e^{(-a x^2)}dx}}dx 
\end{align}
Now we know that $\int{x e^{(-a x^2)}}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-a{x}^{2}}}}{a}}$. using this, we will get
\begin{align}
\int{x^2 e^{(-a x^2)}}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {x{{\rm e}^{-a{x}^{2}}}}{a}}+\frac{1}{4} \frac{\sqrt{\pi} erf({\sqrt{a}x})}{a^{3/2}}
\end{align}

Comment: "This is the most common asked question"...no, not even close.

Answer (score 1):

We present first a direct approach here that applied [Leibniz's Rule for Differentiating Under the Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Let $I(a)$ be the function given by

$$I(a)=\int_a^\infty e^{-ax^2}\,dx \tag 1$$

Enforcing the substitution $x \to x/\sqrt{a}$ yields

$$\begin{align}
I(a)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{a^{3/2}}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\left(1-\text{erf}(a^{3/2})\right) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

where the error function $\text{erf}(x)$ is given by

$$\text{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt$$

Differentiating the right-hand sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$ and equating results reveals

$$\begin{align}
-\int_a^\infty x^2e^{-ax^2}\,dx-e^{-a^3}&=-\frac14\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^3}}\left(1-\text{erf}(a^{3/2})\right)-\frac34 \sqrt{\pi}\text{erf}'(a^{3/2})\\\\
&=-\frac14\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^3}}\left(1-\text{erf}(a^{3/2})\right)-\frac32 e^{-a^3}\tag 3
\end{align}$$

Finally, solving $(3)$ for the term of interest, we obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_a^\infty x^2e^{-ax^2}\,dx=\frac14\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^3}}\left(1-\text{erf}(a^{3/2})\right)+\frac12 e^{-a^3}}$$

as was to be shown.

---

We can derive the formula in question in a similar way.  Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
J(a)&=\int e^{-ax^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\text{erf}(\sqrt{a}\,x)+C(a)
\end{align}$$

where $C(a)$ is an integration constant.  Now, upon differentiating with respect to $a$, we find

$$\begin{align}
-\int x^2 e^{-ax^2}\,dx&=-\frac14 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^3}}\text{erf}(\sqrt{a}\,x)+\frac{x}{2a}e^{-ax^2}+C'(a) \tag 4\\\\
\end{align}$$

whereupon solving $(4)$ for the term of interest yields

$$\int x^2 e^{-ax^2}\,dx=\frac14 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^3}}\text{erf}(\sqrt{a}\,x)-\frac{x}{2a}e^{-ax^2}-C'(a)$$

When evaluating the indefinite integral between lower and upper limits of integration, the contribution from $C'(a)$ is zero.  Therefore, we can drop the integration constant and simply write

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int x^2 e^{-ax^2}\,dx=\frac14 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^3}}\text{erf}(\sqrt{a}\,x)-\frac{x}{2a}e^{-ax^2}}$$